# KeyFrameAnimation won't let me manually override animated Value after Animation is finished

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a Window with a KeyFrameAnimation FadeIn Effect

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FadeIn">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="window" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.8" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BusyAnimation_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeIn}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

In Code Behind I am handling MouseEnter and MouseLeave:

```
    private void FancyNotificationView_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SetValue(Window.OpacityProperty, 1.0);
        Debug.WriteLine((double) GetValue(Window.OpacityProperty));
    }

    private void FancyNotificationView_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SetValue(Window.OpacityProperty, 0.8);
    }
```

As long as the Trigger is active this will not work. Somehow the Animation is in the way of letting me set these Properties by Hand. How can I keep the animation and have MouseEnter and MouseLeave behave the way I intended?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't find a solution. I removed the animation for now.